# Split text file into multiple files c++

Tags: c++, split

I'm trying to split txt file into few new files. That's what I've done so far:

```
long c = 0;
string s;
vector<string> v;
```

I need to count how many lines my txt file has (it works):

```
while(getline(inputFile, s, '\n')){
    v.push_back(s);
    c++;
}

long lineNumber = c;
long max = 100;

long nFiles;
```

checking how many new files will be created:

```
if((lineNumber % max) ==0)
    nFiles = lineNumber/max;
else
    nFiles = lineNumber/max + 1;
```

creating new names of files:

```
long currentLine = 0;

for(long i = 1; i <= nFiles; i++){
    stringstream sstream;
    string a_i;
    sstream <<i;
    sstream >> a_i;

    string outputfiles =  "name" +"_" + a_i  +".txt";

    ofstream fout(outputfiles.c_str());


    for (int j = currentLine; j<max; j++){
        fout << v[j]<<endl;                         
    }

    fout.close();
    currentLine = max;


}
inputFile.close();
```

It creates files but then suddenly stops working. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Have you run your code in a debugger?  Where in the code does it stop working?

Comment: Yes I did. Here is what I get: "program received signal sigsegv segmentation fault"

Comment: There should be a line number at where the segmentation fault happened.

Comment: it's that line: fout << line[j]<<endl;

Comment: When you got that message in your debugger, you were also told what line of code caused the problem.  And you were given the opportunity to inspect the values stored in your variables.  It sounds like the most valuable thing you could know now is not so much the solution to this one problem, but *how to use a debugger*.

Comment: Nothing to do with your problem, but a much simpler way to get each filename would be `std::ostringstream fn; fn << newName << '_' << i << ".txt"; std::ofstream fout( fn.str().c_str() );`.  (Also: you should check the status of `fout` after the close.  If for some reason writing to one of the output files fails, you want to inform the user.  _And_ return a failure code from `main`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a prime example of a time where using a debugger could help you out.

You loop here:

```
for (int j = currentLine; j<max; j++){
    fout << line[j]<<endl;                      
}

fout.close();
currentLine = max;
max = max + nMax;
```

`max` can be bigger than the size of `line` and this will cause a segmentation fault when you try to access `line[j]`. This inner loop really should check that you are not going over the length of `line` which you could find with `line.size()`. Even after you fix this the program logic isn't quite right, `line` doesn't appear to grow in size yet in each iteration of the outer loop you make the accesses to `line` move an additional `max` indexes along, this will always fail in the last file you try to write if you don't stop the loop at the end of `line`.